# How do you check if a user has bought an in-app purchase whenever he open the app?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Note: I'm talking about a one-time purchase that removes ads from the app.

Google says you should call `BillingClient.queryPurchases()` in your `onResume()` and `onCreate()` but I'm not sure how to do that.

First off here's the code for the actual in-app purchase,
I just got it from a youtube tutorial and I don't even know if it's complete:

```
private void setupBillingClient(Context c) { //connect to google play
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(c)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener(this)
            .build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                //The BillingClient is setup successfully
                loadAllSkus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            //TODO: implement retry logic to handle lost connections to Google Play by calling startConnection() again
        }
    });
}

private void loadAllSkus() {
    if (billingClient.isReady()) { //first check if BillingClient is ready
        final SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkusList(skuList)
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                .build();

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull final BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    assert skuDetailsList != null;
                    for (Object skuDetailsObject : skuDetailsList) {
                        final SkuDetails skuDetails = (SkuDetails) skuDetailsObject;
                        if (skuDetails.getSku().equals(sku)) { //if it found the sku in play store you can start billing flow
                            Purchase.PurchasesResult result = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP); //use play store cache, no network
                            List<Purchase> purchases = result.getPurchasesList();
                            boolean isOwned = false;
                            if (purchases != null) //first check if he has already purchased
                                for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                                    String thisSKU = purchase.getSku();
                                    if (thisSKU.equals(sku)) {
                                        isOwned = true;
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You are a premium user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//TODO: Delete this toast
                                        //TODO: Remove purchase options and ads here
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                            if (!isOwned) {
                                buyButton.setEnabled(true);
                                buyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams
                                                .newBuilder()
                                                .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                                                .build();

                                        if (getActivity() != null)
                                            billingClient.launchBillingFlow(getActivity(), billingFlowParams);
                                        dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        /* else if (skuDetails.getSku().equals("something else")) { //add other products

                        }*/
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } else Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.billing_not_ready, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase> purchases) {
    int responseCode = billingResult.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            handlePurchase(purchase); //acknowledge the purchase
        }
    } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
        //already owned
    } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {

    }
}

private void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
    if (purchase.getSku().equals(sku) && purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                    AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                            .build();
            billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Purchase Acknowledged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//TODO: Delete this maybe?
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.purchase_done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

So apparently to call `BillingClient.queryPurchases()` I have to rewrite all of the above code in each and every activity?

Answer (score 2):

The method [BillingClient.queryPurchases()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchases) as you know returns a list of all the currently owned purchases items.

Replicating the same code again and again is always an incorrect approach / design.
What you need to do is to encapsulate your code and make it as independent as possible from any Activity or any other component, so it can be reused.

For a better approach check the official billing samples from Google. You will see that all the billing logic is encapsulated so it can be easily reused.

Java: https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/main/ClassyTaxiJava

Kotlin: https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/main/ClassyTaxiAppKotlin

Some clarifications, if you find that the samples are about subscriptions and you need non-consumables, or vice versa. The billing library is the same for both, the difference is only the data to be queried, for example for subscriptions use **BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS** and for non-consumables **BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP**. But the rest, how to connect with billing, how to acknowledge, initiate the purchase flow, etc., is the exactly same for both. There are no separate APIs or different way to implement it, you use the same API and the same implementation just changing what is being queried.

Comment: Ah but that example is for subscriptions. Is there an example for non-consumable in-app purchases? I know they're similar but I'm already so confused and this might add to my confusion :)

Comment: The difference between subscriptions and non-consumables are minimal, 99% of the code is the same for both scenarios, with very minimal changes. I have myself code for both subscriptions and  non-consumables and is the same code for both, just changing a couple of lines. If you check the BillingClientLifecycle class in the google sample, this code could actually be used for everything, just replace all the occurrences of "BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS" by "BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP". Billing connection, acknowledgement, processing, is always the same for both subscriptions and non-consumables

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Android development. That billing samples thing looks overwhelming, so many instructions and everywhere. I only need to know how to check if an in-app purchase was bought in every activity. Should I just move the existing code to a new class?

Comment: Yes it would be better to move everything into a new class independent from any activity. About your concern, notice that the samples are the official ones from the Android team who develops the billing library. Even if it feels overwhelming, the sample is prone to have no errors and be maintained by Google to reflect all new API changes, which will make your work much easier, as the billing library keeps on changing from time to time. The actual "BillingClientLifecycle" class can by reused as it is, just changing the type of product to query, as the logic is the same for any possible scenario

Comment: Hi I have a question: How do I verify that a purchase has been acknowledged? I'm afraid my code isn't acknowledging purchases which will lead them to being refunded

Comment: You are right, not acknowledging will lead to a refund. When getting the list of Purchases, each item has a "isAcknowledged" method to know ifs state.

Comment: Hi Is there a simple link on how to use `queryPurchases()` to check if user has purchased?

Comment: Again, I don't know which parts of the code I should rewrite. If there's just a simple example

Comment: For example should I call `querySkuDetailsAsync` again?

Comment: I agree with @PerracoLabs. It would be better if you use as your ground of truth the official sample, all what you need is in the file <BllingClientLifecycle>. Change the <SUBS> tags by <INAPP> and you are done, everything else is the same. Anything you find in the internet may be old, with bugs, incomplete, or become obsolete when Google changes something, which they do regularly, and in such case you will end up with code that you don't know how to update because you used an internet tutorial which may not get updated anymore at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer. So thankful to everyone.

```
public void setupBillingClient() {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult=billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

            billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS,(billingResult1, list) -> {

                Log.d("billingprocess","purchasesResult.getPurchasesList():"+purchasesResult.getPurchasesList());

                if (billingResult1.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK &&
                        !Objects.requireNonNull(purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()).isEmpty()) {

                    //here you can pass the user to use the app because he has an active subscription
                    Toast.makeText(WebappActivity.this,"subbungSCCCCCriber",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (billingResult1.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK &&
                        Objects.requireNonNull(purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()).isEmpty())  {

                    loadAllSKUs(); // toward the billingflow

                }
```